# Symfony 2 FOSUserBundle and SSO

Tags: symfony, single-sign-on, fosuserbundle

In my symfony 2 application I'm using FOSUserBundle to authenticate users.
Now i'd like to give an option to login users by SSO.
Since there are multiple Idps for the SSO, I'm not sure there's a sufficient bundle for it. Anyone knows a Bundle where i can set multiple Idps?

If not, I might need to make it myself, but I wonder if I can login a user based on email only using FOSUserBundle (without password).
Anyone has experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create yourself your own user provider and they use both FOSUserBundle and your own as explained here:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/multiple_user_providers.html